# Can I convert a str to an int once I read it as a str from a pickle file?

Tags: python

I'm reading from a text file in binary using python pickle, and it reads a number but this number is read as a string, and I want to use it to multiply, can I convert the str to an int value?

```
saveln = input("Please enter score card: ")
try:
    open_file = open(saveln + '.txt', 'rb')
    load_file = pickle.load(open_file)

    print(load_file['name']+" score card: ""\n")
    print("score: "+load_file['score']+"\n")
    open_file.close()
except:
    print("\n score card does not exist!!")
```

so how would I convert the 'score' into an Integra value?

Comment: you can use int(your string) method to convert a string to int

Comment: but technicaly, you're not using a text file - you're using pickled binary representation of some python data... It would be good to read something about reading text files and leave pickling for when you'll feel more comfortable in python..

Comment: Why are you using this blanket exception that obliterates a useful error message and replaces it with a useless one that is printed to the wrong stream?  If you want to suppress the stack trace, do:

Comment: `try: ...  except Exception as e: raise SystemExit(e)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
int(load_file['score'])
```

Comment: is it really as simple as int("score")?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: `int(your_string)`

Comment: Good luck in your coding path;)